# GooglePicker's onChange() function is not being called in React programme

Tags: reactjs, google-picker

here is my GooglePicker

```
<GooglePicker clientId={'ClientID'}
                         developerKey={'API Key'}
                         scope={['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']}
                         onChange={this.onChange}
                         multiselect={true}
                         navHidden={true}
                         authImmediate={false}
                         mimeTypes={['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg']}
                         viewId={'DOCS_IMAGES'}>
               <button type="button" id="pick">Pick File</button>  
            </GooglePicker>
```

here is my onchange function

```
onChange() {
       console.log("Change is logged here");
}
```

I am able to display the picker button and select the file from google drive. But onChange function is not being called. Please let me know the flaw in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send your `onChange` function like the `arrow function`:

```
<GooglePicker clientId={'ClientID'}
                         developerKey={'API Key'}
                         scope={['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']}
                         onChange={(data) => this.onChange(data)}
                         multiselect={true}
                         navHidden={true}
                         authImmediate={false}
                         mimeTypes={['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg']}
                         viewId={'DOCS_IMAGES'}>
               <button type="button" id="pick">Pick File</button>  
            </GooglePicker>
```

Comment: Great! It's working fine now. I have just started GooglePicker,But do not have much idea. And also tried a lot in internet for Googlepicket react implementation, But couldn't find anything. Could you suggest me any link or Docs for this. Thank you

Comment: Great! It's working fine now. I have just started GooglePicker,But do not have much idea. And also tried a lot in internet for Googlepicket react implementation, But couldn't find anything. Could you suggest me any link or Docs for this. Thank you

Comment: @Kishore, GooglePicker is not famous, and I see it first time, I just opened it's source and find problem. I can say they have a [demo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-picker)

Comment: Usually Onchange() is called in a normal way, But in this case ,it is being called with help of Arrow function. is this specific thing because of GooglePicker? or are there any special reason?

Comment: Not sure what is the `data` here but, when you need to call your method with a params, you can't just write `onChange={this.onChange(somParam)}` this function will be called without `onChange`, with first render, to avoiding this behavior usually used arrow func.